# How to Set POST permalink/slug in wordpress using wp_insert_post

Tags: wordpress, slug, permalinks

I m writing simple script using `wp_insert_post()` to post article in blog.
but one problem here, I want to make **Title** and **slug** of an URL different.

How to achieve this?

for example:

Title: **How to make your diet success**

Slug: `7-ways-to-make-succes-Diet`

Answer (score 36):

**post_title** sets the title, and **post_name** sets the slug.
So:

```
// Create post object
$my_post = array(
     'post_title' => 'How to make your diet success',
     'post_name' => '7-ways-to-make-succes-Diet',
     'post_content' => 'my content',
     'post_status' => 'publish',
     'post_author' => 1,
     'post_category' => array(8,39)
  );

// Insert the post into the database
wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

Comment: Hi, is it possible to append the post ID to the end of post_name, so that the slug generated would look like `hello-world-123' where 123 is the post ID being inserted?

Comment: This is what I tried but getting an error `'post_name' => '$title'.'-'$pid',`

Comment: @anagio Try adding this: `, 'post_name' => sanitize_title_with_dashes($title,'','save')`