# How to add more slugs to one permalink

Tags: php, wordpress, url, permalinks, slug

I want my permalink to be accessable via more than one slug.
For example: **example-page.com/contact/1234** or **example-page.com/contact-1234**

To explain my problem: My customer gets an email and he can participate at a quick survey. The email should contain a customized link that leads him to my wordpress site: example-page.com/contact-1234
The slug that's added to the permalink is the customer ID. So this should change. So the 1234 should be variable.

(The email is not generated, so I can add every link manually)

I want to know how I can change the URL to my customers ID's is there a snippet to use?

I hope I don't sound to confusing.

Comment: Do you want the destination pages to be different, or is the same page?

Comment: The destination page is the same - should be example-page.com/contact but displayed with different slugs example-page.com/contact/1234

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do this through the Wordpress admin: 
[How to Create Custom Permalinks in WordPress](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-custom-permalinks-in-wordpress/)

Additionally this thread: [How to Set POST permalink/slug in wordpress using wp_insert_post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897758/how-to-set-post-permalink-slug-in-wordpress-using-wp-insert-post?rq=1).

Comment: Thanks, the customer IDs should only show in this specific post - so I guess the first one is not an option. I don't think the second one will work too. I'm a noob at coding so I don't really understand it. Normally I just copy and paste ;)

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah, there should be a relatively straightforward solution. I'm not sure if it's common enough to find a plugin or anything like that... for this page, you want the customer ID in the URL always? One thing to investigate would be using an HTTP parameter: http://example.com/123-slug?customerid=420.

Comment: I want the customer ID to show on this specific page always :) yeah that sounds great - any code suggestions?